# How to expand on click and shrink on click somewhere else using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am just learning jQuery and I am wondering why my little script doesn't work. It expands, but I can't seem to get it to shrink back down.

```
$('.strech').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        width: '210px'
    }, 500 );
});

$('body').click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.strech')) {
        ('.strech').animate({
            width: '185px'
        }, 500 );
    }
});
```

Comment: no `$`. You need to use the jQuery object. `$('.strech')`.

Comment: Why not get rid if the whole `if` statement? Not really needed.

Comment: sweet, thanks, i should check my stuff better!